# Screen capture utility that supports pasting/dragging/inserting images

Tags: osx, images, screenshot

There are various screen capture tools that have post-capture annotation tools. I'm looking for one where I can insert, drag, and/or paste another image onto the captured image. For example, it could be useful to drag a meme or sticker-type icon (stars, hearts, etc) into the scene.

Skitch and Ember [1] are perhaps the two main OSX screen capture tools, but neither support this capability (nor did Ember's precursor, Little Snapper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Monosnap for Mac](https://monosnap.com) can do it. Use either pasting the image using Cmd+V or drag and dropping it from somewhere else (e.g. from Finder). Also there's a feature to compile multiple screenshots one by one.